# How to use Asynctask? (android, eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask

I want to know how to use AsyncTask i know the code but I don't know what i should write here:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
//what should i write here
return "Executed";
}
```

Comment: you don't know "android asynctask example", I guess.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @xjaphx i did search for that and i din't understand anything

Comment: @tyczj i didn't understand it, so i was hoping for someone to explain it in an easy way

Comment: @user3879781 this tutorial may help you. http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.U9f5Q4BdWpQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** that method is where you need to write whatever process you are doing in a thread (network activity, data processing, etc). With that setup, it will return a string.

**Long answer:** GIYF - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

---

(Very) Basic example:

```
private class GetStringFromNetwork extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
     protected Long doInBackground(String... strings) {
         // here you can use those strings to do some expensive
         // computation or long task, like fetching data from the network.
         // during the task, you can use publishProgress(<Integer value>)
         // to update the method below on how far done your task is.
         return "whatever you got back from the server";
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         // use this to update the UI and tell the user how far done you are
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         // use this to update the UI with your result (the return from doInBackground)
     }
 }
```